# Code to play AVI file in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, video, avi

I am creating an iPhone application, which can play many media formats. I am not able to play AVI file format, where as I am able to play other formats (for e.g. MP3, MP4, MOV etc). When I try to play AVI, it shows black screen and display is hidden. Any suggestions on what I can do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this tutorial on playing video with ffmpeg and SDL, both available for the iPhone.

[An ffmpeg and SDL Tutorial or How to Write a Video Player in Less Than 1000 Lines](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/)

It's written in C, but consider it pseudocode, and adapt it in Objective C accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

.avi is a container format, not a specific audio/video codec. Depending on the contents of the .avi container, it may or may not be possible to decode the video on an iOS device (due to hardware limitations). If it is possible to decode the video in real time, you may have some luck using the libav (*aka* ffmpeg) library to decode it.

Comment: I'm not going to write your application for you. You have some serious work cut out for you here; you may need to do some more research about video formats before you start.